# List splice for each row in column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a column that contains strings. I want to transform this column, so I end up with only the first n words of the string.

I know I need to split the string and then splice the list to keep the first n words. Then I can use join to, well, join them up again. However I'm running into trouble when executing this.

I expected the following to work:

```py
data = [[1, "A complete sentence must have, at minimum, three things: a subject, verb, and an object. The subject is typically a noun or a pronoun."], [2, "And, if there's a subject, there's bound to be a verb because all verbs need a "], [3, "subject. Finally, the object of a sentence is the thing that's being acted upon by the subject."], [4, "So, you might say, Claire walks her dog. In this complete "]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text']) 

df['first_three'] = df['text'].str.split()[:3]
```

But this executes the split command for the first 3 rows instead of keeping the first three words of each row.

So it looks like this:

```
first_three
['A', 'complete', 'sentence', 'must', 'have,', 'at', 'minimum,', 'three', 'things:', 'a', 'subject,', 'verb,', 'and', 'an', 'object.', 'The', 'subject', 'is', 'typically', 'a', 'noun', 'or', 'a', 'pronoun.']
['And,', 'if', "there's", 'a', 'subject,', "there's", 'bound', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'verb', 'because', 'all', 'verbs', 'need', 'a']
['subject.', 'Finally,', 'the', 'object', 'of', 'a', 'sentence', 'is', 'the', 'thing', "that's", 'being', 'acted', 'upon', 'by', 'the', 'subject.']
NaN
```

I would like the column first_three to look like this:

```
first_three
[A, complete, sentence]
[And, if, there's]
[subject, Finally, the]
[So, you, might]
```

So I can join them up and continue.
I know this must be easy to fix, but I can't seem to find a solution.
Would be very grateful for your input.

Comment: There is no error, I am just not getting the desired result.

Comment: try this `df['first_three'] = df['text'].str.split().apply(lambda x : x[:3])`

Comment: Thank you vbrises, this works. Am I correct in saying this applies the function to every row in the column. So it is not preferred to do it for the entire column 'at once' as it where?

Comment: it applies to every row for the 'text' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apply function to extract the required number of elements from the list.

```
df['first_three'] = df['text'].str.split().apply(lambda x : x[:3])
```

If you want some text cleaning also, then you can do like this:

```
df['first_three'] = df['text'].str.replace(",", " ")
df['first_three'] = df['first_three'].apply(lambda x : x.split()[:3])
```

Output

```
first_three
[A, complete, sentence]
[And, if, there's]
[subject., Finally, the]
```